# Uncaught TypeError: vue_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default[{(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}] is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue along with Laravel.
I have faced an error that says (intermediate value) is not a constructor.
Tried using vue-router for the first time with separate route.js file keeping all the routes in one js file.

Here is my main js file that uses vue router

**app.js**

```
window.Vue = require("vue");

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import router from "./route";


Vue.component("example-component", require("./components/ExampleComponent.vue").default);


const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router
});
```

The route.js looks like this

**route.js**

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

let routes = [{
    path: '/dashboard',
    component: require('./components/Dashboard')
}]

export default new VueRouter[{
    mode: 'history',
    routes
}]
```

Did a research on the existing similar posts. But that didnt really help.

And most importantly, when I use the vue-router within the main app.js itself, everything just works very fine.

Comment: When you get an error about a constructor it mostly related to the "new" keyword, can you remove it from the line with "new VueRouter" ?

Comment: Tried that too.
But it results in another error.
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'matched' of undefined"